# Can you explain the elements on this image

Tags: android

Could you tell me what is the circled element no.1 on this image? The one that look like a submenu, but it seams it's not a submenu.

What does the logo in the top left corner mean?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hm, you mean a custom listview with 2 images and a text. It could be, you're right. Regarding the status bar, I was referring to a Bug logo in it.

Comment: yes that is list view ... sorry i dont know what is that bug logo..

Comment: made me to do some research so +1 vote..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selected area consists of

```
1) list view

The listview contains
1) ImageView at the left
2) textView with image background in the middle
3) imageview at the right
```

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: How do you know it is a ListView?

Comment: You say that this is just a transparency effect? Not real transparency?   How did he make one 'android:divider' be colourful, and another pure black?

Comment: @flo Maybe because it resembles ListView and it has 'android:divider' visible

Comment: @flo the structure in the selected image is same. 2 imageview and one textview with background text. instead of creatting four layouts we can use list view and set the view as per position.

Comment: @Deepak: Yes it looks like a list, but you cannot definitely say that it is a ListView. It also might be a custom with a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout as parent layout. I think using a ListView would be too cumbersome as you have to define a custom row layout, a custom adapter to insert the correct icon. And then you implement all this for just showing some kind of menu? I only want to say that we simply cannot say what it is, it might be a ListView, it might not. We'll never know.

Comment: @ askmo it is not colorfull divider. it is just reflecting background

Comment: @everyone Then it is not a TextView with a background, but rather ListView (or any element) with `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`. This background is set to the container View. Am I right?

Comment: (lapsus c.) I meant, "...this shiny background..."

Answer (score 2):

1st one element is the List View

2nd one is might be the symbol of Android HoneyComb but I am not sure about this..

Comment: Honeycomb?! I have a 2.3.3 emulator and I haven't seen this logo ever.

Answer (score 1):

The little bug in the notification bar means, this device can be used for debugging. It appears when the device is connected to a computer and the Debug option on the device is activated.

The menu you see can be everything as you can define custom layouts. So without the source, you'll never know. I don't think it is a ListView as it would be too cumbersome to implement it in that way.

Comment: Cool. Now I wonder who I have never seen it. I may be having a 'bug blindness' :)))

Answer (score 1):

Number one is a styled ListView.

Number two means that the USB Debug mode is on (and the USB cable is connected)
USB Debug mode is normally used by developers.

Answer (score 0):

the image number 1 looks like list view and image number 2 is status bar(Notification bar)

Comment: LOL, you are too fast. I was replying above, when you moved your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

1. may be listview, expandable list view, buttons and any kind of view
2. It look like a bug